# Thymeleaf - Error resolving template "email-inlineimage.html"

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

So, I see all answer this problem in Stackoverflow, but not be of any help to me.
(
[SpringMVC+Thymeleaf ,error message is : template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777425/springmvcthymeleaf-error-message-is-template-might-not-exist-or-might-not-be)

[Error resolving template "pages", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260520/error-resolving-template-pages-template-might-not-exist-or-might-not-be-acces)

[SpringMVC+Thymeleaf ,error message is : template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777425/springmvcthymeleaf-error-message-is-template-might-not-exist-or-might-not-be)

...
)

Here my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

<!-- Basic Configurations -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.podium.italia.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.podium.italia.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.podium.italia.model"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.podium.italia.repository"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<!-- i18n -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/i18n"/>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
</bean>

<!-- Email support -->
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="protocol" value="smtp" />
    <property name="username" value="smmailsender@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="Style@mix2014" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.quitwait">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- THYMELEAF: Template Resolver for email templates -->
<bean id="emailTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="mail/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<!-- THYMELEAF: Template Resolver for webapp pages   -->
<!-- (we would not need this if our app was not web) -->
<bean id="webTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>

<!-- THYMELEAF: Template Engine (Spring3-specific version) -->
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
            <ref bean="webTemplateResolver" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- THYMELEAF: View Resolver - implementation of Spring's ViewResolver interface -->
<!-- (we would not need this if our app was not web)                              -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<import resource="daoContext.xml"/>
```

Here emailService:

```
final WebContext ctx = new WebContext(request,response, request.getServletContext(), locale);

//.....

// Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
final String htmlContent = this.templateEngine.process("email-inlineimage.html", ctx);
message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);
```

And Error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "email-
inlineimage.html", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the
configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:245)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:924)
org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:898)
com.podium.italia.service.EmailService.sendMailWithInlineImages(EmailService.java:112)
```

Comment: Where does "email-inlineimage.html" exist? can you share the pathing to this file?

Comment: Can you possibly share a project?

Comment: Tell us there is a problem finding a resource but don't tell us the structure of your application...

Comment: no I can't share project, I deleted its and wrote native java send mail with inline image code, but if anybody answer to me with working example I will give it bounty and I would accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't spot error in your `servlet-context.xml` so problem must be buried somewhere else (are you sure you have template file on classpath exactly at `mail/email-inlineimage.html`?). I'm providing working example as whole project (since it's overkill to paste everything to code samples here) which you can import to [STS](http://spring.io/tools) and run.

[Spring Thymeleaf Mailing](http://www.kreuzman.com/java/spring.thymeleaf.mailing.zip)